# Python asyncio queue use get/put simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'd like to run a Python script that can simulate real-world time-series data and process the data in real-time. That is to say, from a given dataset, (which is ~8hr long measurement), I want to get one-second-long data every second, and process as soon as each second of data is read. In the real world, the data will be gathered every second using some detectors. For this task, I've decided to use Python `asyncio` module. Below is basically what I came up with.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import asyncio
import time
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

async def get_data (data):

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        q.put(data[idx,:])
        idx += 1
        #Each row of data is read every second. 

async def run_algorithm ():

    while True:

        if q.empty() == True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

        data_read = q.get(block = False)

        #I do something here with the read data


async def main (data):

    feed_data = asyncio.create_task(get_data(data))
    process_data = asyncio.create_task(run_algorithm ())
    await asyncio.gather(feed_data, process_data)
```

While it seems to work fine, the problem is that #I do something here with the read data part. That is where I use my algorithm to process the data in real-time. When I use an algorithm that is fast, it works pretty well. It reads the data every second as it should, and the run_algorithm function waits for a second when there is no data in the queue.

However, when I have a slow algorithm, it does not read the data every second. If the algorithm takes 0.5 seconds to run, then the next data is read in 1.5 seconds, instead of 1 second.

It is like the get_data function slows down as run_algorithm part slows down. Is there a way to get that get_data read the data every second no matter how long the run_algorithm part takes?

Comment: Why are you using a `queue.Queue` instead of an `asyncio.Queue`?

Comment: ^^ and if you were to use that approach you could get rid of the sleep statements completely

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I never tried asyncio.Queue, I'll try it right now.

Comment: @gold_cy Could you elaborate? I don't quite understand how I can get rid of sleep.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am getting the same issue with asyncio.Queue()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you need to use an asyncio queue, in which case you don't need the sleeps in `run_algorithm`:

```
q = asyncio.Queue()

async def get_data (data):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await q.put(data[idx,:])
        idx += 1
        #Each row of data is read every second. 

async def run_algorithm ():
    while True:
        data_read = await q.get()
        #I do something here with the read data
```

> However, when I have a slow algorithm, it does not read the data every second

It sounds like your algorithm contains CPU-bound or otherwise blocking code. Since asyncio is single-threaded, this causes the event loop to stall. To fix it, you should run blocking code in a separate thread. Asyncio contains a utility for this purpose, [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). For example, emulating the blocking/CPU-bound call with `time.sleep(1)` (intentionally *not* using `asyncio.sleep` here to emulate blocking), here is how you would call it from asyncio:

```
        #time.sleep(1)   # this is forbidden
        # instead, invoke blocking code like this:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like:

```
from time import monotonic

async def get_data (data):
    start = monotonic() 
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        delay = start + i - monotonic()
        if delay > 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        q.put(data[i,:])
```

i.e. track when you started, then just sleep for the remaining delay.  note that this will tend to cause a many items to be added if the consumer is too slow for one of them

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it. The data is not read consistently in 1 second though. Sometimes it reads two data at the same time, sometimes it skips reading a data, but on average it does work.

Comment: what do you mean by "read consistently in 1 second"?  if the consuming process is consistently slow then there's not much that can be done.  if the consuming process is doing computationally heavy work (as suggested by use of numpy) then it will block things and you probably just want to use threads (rather than asyncio)